# MongDB Atlas SRV Connection Using Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, morphia, mongodb-atlas

Am using [morphia](https://morphia.dev/) Version 1.5.8 which has mongodb driver 3.10.1.

Have received an srv url like below from atlas
`mongodb+srv://username:password@clusterurl/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Am trying simply like this as per the documentation

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
    "mongodb+srv://username:password@clusterurl/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority");

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(<databasename>);
```

Below is the error am getting

I could see an error already filed in the [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-3402) regarding this. Any other options that I will be able to connect with srv url to atlas?

My underlying framework used in application is `Play`

**JVM Details**

```
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
```

**Error**

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoClientException: Unable to support mongodb+srv// style connections as the 'com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory' class is not available in this JRE. A JNDI context is required for resolving SRV records.
    at com.mongodb.internal.dns.DefaultDnsResolver.createDnsDirContext(DefaultDnsResolver.java:152)
    at com.mongodb.internal.dns.DefaultDnsResolver.resolveAdditionalQueryParametersFromTxtRecords(DefaultDnsResolver.java:112)
    at com.mongodb.ConnectionString.<init>(ConnectionString.java:371)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientURI.<init>(MongoClientURI.java:244)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientURI.<init>(MongoClientURI.java:226)
    at modules.providers.MongoClientProvider.get(MongoClientProvider.java:28)
    at modules.providers.MongoClientProvider.get(MongoClientProvider.java:16)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:158)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:155)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:155)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:124)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:124)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:116)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: javax.naming.ConfigurationException: Invalid DNS pseudo-URL(s):
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory.urlToContext(DnsContextFactory.java:108)
    at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory.getInitialContext(DnsContextFactory.java:64)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.internal.dns.DefaultDnsResolver.createDnsDirContext(DefaultDnsResolver.java:150)
    ... 59 more
```

Comment: Mongo Srv URL is correct and able to connect from Mongo Shell. If I use nodes url things are working as expected.

Comment: As the [comment](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-3402?focusedCommentId=2439994&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-2439994) says - it's not working, you have to use full non-SRV url or wait until it's fixed.

Comment: I am facing same issue with openjdk11 build.